# How to run a Python script inside another script and close itself immediately

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a login frame and a main frame that made from pyqt.
I want to run the main command after I clicked the button and when the main frame runs close the login frame.

I wrote a def for clicking button but when the command executed the main frame still waits until I close the main window.

This is the function of clicking the button:

```
def ButtonClicked(self):

       os.system('py Main.py')
       self.os.exit()
```

How can I make it close immediately and not wait for main.py to exit?

Comment: `start "" py Main.py`

Comment: i dont get it what is the start

Comment: `os.system('start "" py Main.py')`

Comment: @PeterWood thanks alot it worked ,but i have a little bug that is when the os.system('start "" py Main.py') runs the console start but not comes popop. i should press it on taskbar to show

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your approach is the best here, but just to answer your specific question: `os.system` is not the right function here since it waits for the output of the call before continuing (as you might have noticed...). Try to "spawn" a process and tell Python not to wait for any result with something like this:

```
os.spawnl(os.P_DETACH, 'py Main.py')
```

---

**EDIT**

Given the comments I'll change the answer a bit. To use `spawnl` in a "with path" mode you have to add a `p` at the end (`spawnlp()`). Although the os.system and os.spawn** provide basic functionality, the docs refer to the subprocess library for better control. It makes stuff a little more complicated but I think this example does what you ask for:

```
import sys
import subprocess

# Constant for detaching a process
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008

# Start the process and get its PID
pid = subprocess.Popen(["python", "you_second_script.py"], close_fds=True, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS).pid
print(pid)

# The end of this script, the started process will continue
sys.exit()
```

Comment: [**`os.spawnl`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.spawnl) doesn't use `PATH` to locate `py`

Comment: thanks for the answer , but @PeterWood answer helped me through this